# Regex to parse CustomLog format (PHP)

Tags: php, regex, apache, logging

I am trying to parse a CustomLog format in this format:

```
LogFormat "%v %{X-Forwarded-For}i %h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b" MyCustomLog
```

This is how the entry looks - note that there is a comma delimiting the IP's passed in the X-Forwarded-For header.

```
my.server.com 24.24.24.3, 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5 - - [18/May/2016:02:57:25 -0400] "GET /veer/eye?params=1&are=2&right=3&here=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 146351
```

I want to capture the following fields:

- x-forward-for IP's (comma delimited)
- remote hostname
- remote logname (may be -)
- remote user (may be -)
- timestamp in [ ] block
- the request url (in the quotes)
- the response size (the last value)

I am a bit rusty with regex - at least in the sense of negative lookaheads which is what i think i need to use?

Help is appreciated!

Comment: do you really need negative lookahead here?

Comment: i thought so, but by your comment probably not! Shows how rusty I am! :)

Comment: it seems you can explode on space and `,` and get the vaues

Comment: I thought that - but that would include the spaces in the comma delimited X-Forwarded-For IP's

Comment: can you tell the value of `x-forward-for IP's `?

Comment: X-Forwarded-For in this case is 24.24.24.3, 1.2.3.4

Comment: and remote hostname is `1.2.3.5`?

Comment: have a look at **[this](https://regex101.com/r/sF2uD2/1)**

Comment: looks good - but will the \d match '-'

Comment: `[(\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?:,\s*(?:\d+(?:\.\d+){3}))*)\s+(\d+(?:\.\d+){3})\s+([^\s+])\s+([^\s+])\s+(\[.*?\])\s+"([^"]+)"\s+[^\s]*\s+(.*)$](https://regex101.com/r/qS7cP5/2)`

Comment: I get this error: Warning Error: preg_match(): Compilation failed: nothing to repeat at offset 81 in [/opt/log/app/src/Shell/ImportShell.php, line 69]

Comment: see **[here](https://regex101.com/r/qS7cP5/2)**

Comment: works fine **[here](http://ideone.com/JgTmCt)**

Comment: are you able to parse this line? ::     qa-test.test.com - 80.82.65.120 - - [18/May/2016:00:30:20 -0400] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 404 198

Comment: it will fail outright because there is no remote-hostname

Comment: Is there a way to make it disregard it in that case?

Comment: that can be done..but then there will be cases where anything else will not be present and then anything else

Comment: i mean now its missing `remote-hostname` ..in any other case it will miss  `timestamp in [ ] block`

Comment: When I run your code, I get the second IP in the X-F-F duplicated

Comment: Instead of printing 1.2.3.5, it prints 1.2.3.4 twice

Comment: Nevermind, my mistake. Can you create an answer?

Comment: not today..because I have reached maximum limit of 200 reputation..and I will gain no reputation after answering this(_yes I love to get points..who doesn't?_)..will update tomorrow

Comment: @rock321987 you do know that you can get more than 200 points. The rep cap only applies to upvotes, not accepted answers (+15 points) and bounties (which offer whatever the bounty is). And if someone later, after today, upvotes your answer you do still get those points.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn i already have 20 upvotes today(_and lost few because I was not aware of what actually happens due to this rule_)..and the rule is still confusing for me..

Comment: @rock321987 Like I said though, you get rep from OP accepting your answer, just not from the upvotes. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/how-does-reputation-work covers pretty much everything reputation related including how the cap works.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn will read tomorrow..thanks for the link..its time to sleep

Comment: Well, if you are not going to post anything, then I will as the question needs answer for OP to close.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a more complete pattern that should work for you. I break everything out as part of a group more completely and even added names for the groups. It matches both the example found in your question and the one in the comments.

Demo: https://3v4l.org/jMKFL

```
<?php
$pattern = '/(?P<hostname>[\w\.]+) '
         . '(?P<forwardedFor>(?:[\d\.]+, )*(?:[\d\.]+)|-) '
         . '(?P<remoteHostname>[\d\.]+) '
         . '(?P<remoteLogname>[^\s]+) '
         . '(?P<remoteUsername>[^\s]+) '
         . '\['
            . '(?P<requestDate>[^\]]+)'
         . '\] '
         . '"'
            . '(?P<method>\w+) '
            . '(?P<uri>[^\s]+) '
            . '(?<httpVersion>[^\"]+)'
         . '" '
         . '(?P<responseStatus>\d+) '
         . '(?P<responseSize>\d+)/';

$test = 'my.server.com 24.24.24.3, 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5 - - [18/May/2016:02:57:25 -0400] "GET /veer/eye?params=1&are=2&right=3&here=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 146351';
$test2 = 'qa-test.test.com - 80.82.65.120 - - [18/May/2016:00:30:20 -0400] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 404 198';

preg_match($pattern, $test, $matches);
print_r($matches);

preg_match($pattern, $test2, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Outputs:

```
Array
(
    [0] => my.server.com 24.24.24.3, 1.2.3.4 1.2.3.5 - - [18/May/2016:02:57:25 -0400] "GET /veer/eye?params=1&are=2&right=3&here=4 HTTP/1.1" 200 146351
    [hostname] => my.server.com
    [1] => my.server.com
    [forwardedFor] => 24.24.24.3, 1.2.3.4
    [2] => 24.24.24.3, 1.2.3.4
    [remoteHostname] => 1.2.3.5
    [3] => 1.2.3.5
    [remoteLogname] => -
    [4] => -
    [remoteUsername] => -
    [5] => -
    [requestDate] => 18/May/2016:02:57:25 -0400
    [6] => 18/May/2016:02:57:25 -0400
    [method] => GET
    [7] => GET
    [uri] => /veer/eye?params=1&are=2&right=3&here=4
    [8] => /veer/eye?params=1&are=2&right=3&here=4
    [httpVersion] => HTTP/1.1
    [9] => HTTP/1.1
    [responseStatus] => 200
    [10] => 200
    [responseSize] => 146351
    [11] => 146351
)
Array
(
    [0] => test.test.com - 80.82.65.120 - - [18/May/2016:00:30:20 -0400] "GET // HTTP/1.1" 404 198
    [hostname] => test.test.com
    [1] => test.test.com
    [forwardedFor] => -
    [2] => -
    [remoteHostname] => 80.82.65.120
    [3] => 80.82.65.120
    [remoteLogname] => -
    [4] => -
    [remoteUsername] => -
    [5] => -
    [requestDate] => 18/May/2016:00:30:20 -0400
    [6] => 18/May/2016:00:30:20 -0400
    [method] => GET
    [7] => GET
    [uri] => //
    [8] => //
    [httpVersion] => HTTP/1.1
    [9] => HTTP/1.1
    [responseStatus] => 404
    [10] => 404
    [responseSize] => 198
    [11] => 198
)
```